# Why does COALESCE order results in this way?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with three columns, id, comment, and parent. If parent id is null, the comment is the root comment, and if it is not, this means the comment is a reply to another. I use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `comment` 
ORDER BY COALESCE( parent, id ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This query orders the last inserted comment with it's replies, but I don't understand the logic. Why is it ordered this way?

[image]

Comment: @piotrm so why NULL column come first? NULL have more priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `COALESCE()` function returns the [first non-null argument](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) that is received. So, if you go through each row and compare the parent/id column, you'll see that it is ordered like this:

```
7 (because parent is null)
2 (because parent is null)
2 (parent is not null, so it is used)
1 (because parent is null)
1 (parent is not null, so it is used)
1 (parent is not null, so it is used)
```

Which is in descending order, as you specified.

---

I suspect there may be some confusion here. So let me reiterate. `COALESCE(parent, id)` will return the first value out of those two that is *not null*. If parent is not null, it is returned. If it is null, it falls back on id and returns that. If you look at a list of those rows side by side and see the return values, it may be more clear:

```
| parent | id | return_value |
+--------+----+--------------+
|  null  | 7  |       7      |
|  null  | 2  |       2      |
|  2     | 4  |       2      |
|  null  | 1  |       1      |
|  1     | 3  |       1      |
|  1     | 5  |       1      |
|  1     | 6  |       1      |
```

Comment: i can't understand why the null colimn first? can u trace code, specially the order section

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy I have edited the answer, I hope it helps. It's not null that's coming first, but 7 is coming first because it is the highest value returned by `COALESCE(parent, id)`

Comment: @MaAdam331 ok , but what the meaning of order by 7?

Comment: @MaAdam or mybe it return id itself, order by id for example?

Comment: If you go through the table and preform `COALESCE(parent, id)` you'll get a group of integers: (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 7). Then, as you've written your query, you'll order in DESC order, which brings you to (7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1).

Comment: Yes, by default it will be returned ordered by comment id, and changes once you've added the order by clause to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `comment` 
ORDER BY parent DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

First comes the sort by parent (NULLs sort after ints)

4653

and then

sorting by id in reverse order

721

That will give

4
6
5
3
7
2
1

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I don't think they're trying to change the query, but understand why the one the have is returning the way it is.

Comment: @McAdam331 Fair point, and I kinda knew that. I was just thinking that an alternative view might help the OP understand the logic behind the sort better.

Comment: That's always worth adding too!